# How to add constant force to player with sperical gravity planet.?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, rigidbody, physics

I have a planet and character. My player move perfect around planet with pressing key like 'w','s','a and 'D'. I want to move my player on every frame with same force around sphere. I try plane surface constant force code  like this `this.rigidbody.AddForce ( 3f,3f,3f);`, when start playing game this code work fine but after some movement it stop my player on specific position of planet. I want to use this code for 3D sphere.

Any one can help me how can add constant force to my player on 3d sphere.?

I want add constant force to player when game start. I don't want any kind of planet's orbits, because my player is moving on all over the planet.

I try below link but it did not working for me.
 [How can i accurately simulate orbits in unity.?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106623/how-can-i-accurately-simulate-orbits-in-unity)

**Here is my Sctipts**

**PlayerController.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed = 10;
public Vector3 moveDir;
Rigidbody rigidbody;
// Update is called once per frame3

void Start(){
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}
void Update () {

    moveDir = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")  ,0,Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
}
void FixedUpdate(){

    rigidbody.MovePosition (rigidbody.position + transform.TransformDirection(moveDir) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

 }
}
```

**FauxGravityBody.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
public class FauxGravityBody : MonoBehaviour {

public FauxGravityAttractor attractor;
public Transform myTransform;
Rigidbody rigidbody;

// Use this for initialization++
void Awake(){

    this.rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

}
void Start () {
    myTransform = transform;
    rigidbody.useGravity = false;
    rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    attractor.Attract (myTransform);
  }
}
```

**FauxGravityAttractor.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FauxGravityAttractor : MonoBehaviour {

public float gravity = -10;
public void Attract(Transform body){

    Vector3 gravityUp = (body.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Vector3 bodyUp = body.up;

    body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (gravityUp * gravity);
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (bodyUp, gravityUp) * body.rotation;
    body.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (body.rotation, targetRotation, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
  }
}
```

I am working with this scripts, If any one help me? then please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I accurately simulate orbits in Unity?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106623/how-can-i-accurately-simulate-orbits-in-unity)

Comment: This is not duplicate. You put link for planet orbit. I don't  want to move my player with orbit. My player is playing and jumping in all over the planet. @Philipp

Comment: I want to apply constant force to my player with game start. By using your linked question script i can't do that. @Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Faux gravity system in Unity and it works with jumping as well. TThis is the youtube link - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gHeQ8Hr92P4&fulldescription=1&client=mv-google&gl=ZW&hl=en.  The download link for the unity project seems to be dead though. Ive uploaded the project to my mediafire account. I'l also add it to github when i get on a PC. link - http://www.mediafire.com/download/o7w7mogd6w3a4jc/Faux_Gravity_Example.7z

Edit 1: Adding constand force-
In order to add a constant force to the player object, in the Player Controller script, edit the update method. Replace all the code in update with this

`moveDirection = new Vector3(1,0,1);`

I suggest you take a look at some basic C# tutorials before jumping into Unity. If this is for a school project or assignment, you wont learn much doing things this way. good luck.

Comment: I see your tutorial and its not for unity 5. I change the scripts given in tutorial for unity 5, but still result is same. player not start moving around sphere with game start. I must have to press W,A,S and D key to move player. @zimspy

Comment: I updated the scripts using Unity's Api updater before re-uploading them.

Comment: Sorry for this, I forget this little thing. If I use `Input.GetAxisRaw` then i have to add value by pressing keys at runtim, and If i want to transform it directly with game start then I can specify value in `Update()` method and also I can set it at runtime by using variable. thanx for saving my time and brain.