# How to have 3d multiple planet gravity in unity c#?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, planet

Im using unity and I want to make a game where you can walk around small planets and the further away you get, the weaker the gravity, so you can go to other planets. All the tutorials so far only work with one planet, how do I code this? Is there anything I can download that does it for me?

Comment: How are you handling your gravity so far?

Comment: You can [add forces](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to your objects pointing in any direction you like. So walking around the surface of a planet should be a matter of adding a force to simulate acceleration towards the centre of mass. If you have multiple moving planets and want accurate gravity continuously between them, things get rather more complex

Comment: Does the script I posted on [this question help you](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106623/how-can-i-accurately-simulate-orbits-in-unity/106624#106624)?